# How do I ensure that certain folders in Windows 7 is not shared?

Tags: shared-folders

I want to share folder

Then I want to unshare folder/subfolder

So, how to do so?

I choose share with nobody and yet other computer can still see the folder

Comment: “Subdomain”?​​​

Comment: Change that to subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide folder inside a shared folder, it is not possible.

What you can do is either hide your root share simply by adding $ to the end of the share name, or prevent access to sub folders with NTFS permissions.

Comment: what's ntfs permissions?

Comment: Here are some links:
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html
http://technet.microsoft.com/magazine/84f96ea7-f6ae-4c50-92a9-e6981631cb6d